# ColorFuntion input

Tags: color

Is there any input for `ColorFunction`, which ranges from Black for smallest values, goes through red-orange-yellow and ends in very bright yellow almost white for the highest values of the `ListDensityPlot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can either pick one here:

```
{#, ColorData@#} & /@ ColorData["Gradients"] // Short
```

[image]

or create your own with `Hue`:

```
col = Function[Blend[{Black, Hue@.05, Hue@.15, White}, Slot[1]]]
```

or by naming the colours you want:

```
col1 = Function[Blend[{Black, Red, Orange, Yellow, White}, Slot[1]]]

ListDensityPlot[Table[1/(x^2 + y^2), {x, -2, 2, 4/51}, {y, -2, 2, 4/51}], 
  ColorFunction -> #]& /@ {col, col1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Look at some candiates:

```
Grid[Partition[
  Show[ColorData[#, "Image"], ImageSize -> 110] & /@ (cd = 
     ColorData["Gradients"]), 4, 4, 1, {}], Spacings -> .5]
```

[image]

Number 47 looks interesting...

```
cd[[47]]
ColorData[%, "Image"]

(* SunsetColors *)
```

[image]